# TK Image Not Appearing

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to put an image on a TKinter canvas with other buttons under the image. For some reason I can not get this picture to appear. I have not yet implemented the buttons. Here is my code thus far.

```
class GUI_Control:
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player
        self.map = Tk()
        self.MAP_WIDTH = 600
        self.MAP_HEIGHT = 375
        #define map gui here
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.map, width=self.MAP_WIDTH, height=self.MAP_HEIGHT)
        self.map_picture = PhotoImage(file=r"images/archipelago.gif")
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.map_picture)
        #define level gui's here

    def open(self):
        self.map.mainloop()

    def hide_map(self):
        self.map.destroy()


#debugging
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = GUI_Control(Player.Player())
    gui.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use one of Tk’s geometry-management mechanisms to tell it where to render the canvas within it's container.

the simplest way would be to add `self.canvas.pack()` like so:

```
    #define map gui here
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.map, width=self.MAP_WIDTH, height=self.MAP_HEIGHT)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.map_picture = PhotoImage(file=r"images/archipelago.gif")
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.map_picture)
    #define level gui's here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `pack()` (or `grid()`) method of widgets for them to be displayed:

```
class GUI_Control:
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player
        self.map = Tk()
        self.MAP_WIDTH = 600
        self.MAP_HEIGHT = 375
        #define map gui here
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.map, width=self.MAP_WIDTH, height=self.MAP_HEIGHT)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)  # ADDED
        self.map_picture = PhotoImage(file="images/archipelago.gif")
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.map_picture, anchor='nw')
        #define level gui's here

    def open(self):
        self.map.mainloop()

    def hide_map(self):
        self.map.destroy()

#debugging
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = GUI_Control(Player.Player())
    gui.open()
```